# How can i make this disconnect command work?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

How can I make this disconnect command work?

Example: ~dc 20m

And it will dc the user after 20 min. and if the user is not in a VC it will say: you must be in a VC first.

this is what I tried but it ended up not working. how can I make it work?

```js
if (message.content === "~dc (time)") {
    let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed();
})
```

Comment: First you'll have to set up arguments to take in user input. Learn how to use args http://discordjs.guide/creating-your-bot/commands-with-user-input.html